# Apex get param from picklist input

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to create a dynamic picklist from two custom object, Region and country.
So we have a LWC with two picklist one for Region and one from Country and the behaviour should be that when the user selects a Region in the picklist it will display in the country picklist only the Countries of that region.
So my Apex code is the following:

```
public with sharing class PicklistHelper {
public PicklistHelper() {

}
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Map<String,String> getRegion(){
    Map<String,String> regionMap = new Map<String,String>();
    for(Region__c regionObj:[select id,name from Region__c ]){
        regionMap.put(regionObj.Id,regionObj.Name);
    }
    return regionMap;
}

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Map<String,String> getCountry(string selectedRegion){
    Map<String,String> CountryMap = new Map<String,String>();
    for(Country__c countryObj:[select id,name from Country__c where Region__c = selectedRegion]){
        CountryMap.put(countryObj.Id,countryObj.Name);
    }
    return CountryMap;
}
```

}

and my js code looks like:

```
import { LightningElement,wire } from 'lwc';
import getRegion from '@salesforce/apex/PicklistHelper.getRegion';
import getCountry from '@salesforce/apex/PicklistHelper.getCountry';

export default class FilterPanel extends LightningElement {
    regionOptionsList;
    selectedRegion;
    countryOptionsList;
    selectedCountry;


@wire(getRegion)
retrieveRegion({error, data}){
    let tempArray = []
    if(data){
        for(let key in data){
            tempArray.push({label:data[key], value:key}); 
        }
    }
    this.regionOptionsList = tempArray;
}

handleRegionChange(event){
    this.selectedRegion = event.target.value;
}

@wire(getCountry)
retrieveCountry({error, data}){
    let CountrytempArray = []
    if(data){
        for(let key in data){
            CountrytempArray.push({label:data[key], value:key}); 
        }
    }
    this.countryOptionsList = CountrytempArray;
}

handleCountryChange(event){
    this.selectedCountry = event.target.value;
}

}
```

For some reason I do not get my code to work I get an error from the apex code that "Unexpected token 'selectedRegion'.'

So my question is how do I pass a value from my LWC to Apex back to LWC

Thx you

Comment: `... Region__c = selectedRegion` For this problem, in your SOQL you are missing a colon. It should be  `... Region__c = :selectedRegion `

Comment: Nicee thx you.. this part is working but the behaviour still not ..
I think I am not passing the selectedRegion parameter here @wire(getCountry).. 
WOuld you know how to do it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the section on [Wire an Apex Method with a Dynamic Parameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_wire_method).

You need to pass in a second parameter (an object with your Apex parameters) to the wire method:

Change:

```
@wire(getCountry)
```

To this:

```
@wire(getCountry, {selectedRegion:'$selectedRegion'})
```